# hard drive encryption

Tags: upgrade, hard-drive, 18.04, encryption

I have upgraded my ubuntu version and now when I start the PC it does not accept anymore the password for the hard drive encryption

What can I do?

thanks
francesco

Answer (score 0):

Load Ubuntu from Live USB. Mount partition where your encrypted home directory reside (from Nautilus for example). Assume the home directory mounted to `/media/ubuntu/myHome`. Then try in terminal:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /media/ubuntu/myHome/.ecryptfs/user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

where `user` is your user name - replace it.

You'll be asked for your user password and then you'll see your encryption real passphrase - copy and save it to a text file. Next run:

```
sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
```

Enter you passphrase obtained from previous command. You'll see two lines with `Inserted auth tok with sig` with something in square brackets like this `[7897fd8789g7dfg]` - copy (without brackets) and save it to text file. We'll need second of keys in square brackets. Next make directory:

```
sudo mkdir /media/ubuntu/decryptedHome
```

and run

```
sudo mount -t ecryptfs /media/ubuntu/myHome/.ecryptfs/user/.Private/ /media/ubuntu/decryptedHome/
```

You'll be asked for some questions - allow default answers except file names decryption - allow file names encrypted and when you'll be asked for files names passphrase enter second key from square brackets `[]`.

If everything was OK you have to find your home directory files in `/media/ubuntu/decryptedHome/` directory.